# Logic Level Indicator Input Voltage

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, indicator

Here's a diagram of a logic level indicator and NAND gate.

[image: Diagram]
[image: NAND gate]

Now I'm supposed to use this in conjunction with some basic logic circuits. However I cannot find out what voltage I should have at the input for the LED to light up, assuming positive logic. Does anyone have an idea of how I could find it via calculations? I'm afraid I've got no idea.

EDIT: Added that it is assuming positive logic.

Comment: Type of logic???

Comment: Sorry, positive logic! I'll edit the question to add that.

Comment: Logic family???

Comment: I'm not certain what you mean, sorry. I'm quite new to logic, and the indicator is being used for NAND gates from a "Quad 2-input NAND gates IC" according to my equipment lists.

Comment: @Andrew: Leon is asking if it's TTL or CMOS logic. The voltage levels for '0' and '1' are different between the two families. Can you add your image inline so all the info is in the question?

Comment: @Transistor: I'm not sure which family it belongs to, but I added a diagram and all the information available about the NAND gate chip, so I hope its possible to find out from that.

Comment: Yes, it's a 74LS family. Your inverter should also be from that family.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. The simple logic level indicator.*

> However I cannot find out what voltage I should have at the input for the LED to light up, ...

The logic level indicator is simply an inverting buffer driving the LED. When the input is 'high' the output will be 'low' and current will flow from the +5 V to the inverter output. (The inverter will 'sink' the current from the LED.) When the input is low the output will be high and there will be no voltage across the LED so it will turn off.

A few things:

- The inverter chip needs to be of the same logic family as the circuit under test so that logic levels (switching voltages) match.
- Additional inverters could be used in parallel to increase the current sinking ability.
- The inverter chip needs to be connected to +5 V and GND.

[image]

*Figure 2. Logic level switching voltages.*

Digital logic became the standard because there are only two states to worry about - '0' or '1'. That means we can allow for some deviation away from 0 V for a logic 0 and some deviation from +5 V for a logic 1. This is important because if a gate is driving multiple other gates the loading will cause the voltage to droop somewhat. Each logic family has its own switching thresholds due to the internal construction.

What Figure 2 is showing you is:

- (1) The V<sub>IH</sub> is the minimum voltage that is guaranteed to be detected as a '1'.
- (2) For your TTL LS family this is 2.0 V and any voltage above 2.0 will give a logic 1.
- (3) The V<sub>IL</sub> is the maximum voltage that is guaranteed to be detected as a '0'.
- (4) For your TTL LS family this is 0.8 V. Any voltage below that will give a logic 0.

The chart also gives other parameters that you can read up on.

Comment: I see, so an input of under 5 volts would activate the LED then?

Comment: See the update. I recommend that you unaccept my answer for a day or two to give the whole of humanity a chance to answer. You might get a better answer or at least some other insights. Then come back and accept the best one, if it really answers your question. Thanks.

Comment: Nice answer, I was going to look for that 2nd diagram, though since you added it there's no point in adding it to mine too. +1

Comment: @SamGibson: Go ahead and expand on it or find a better diagram. You could also mention that for CMOS which can tolerate a wide supply voltage range that the thresholds will scale with the voltage.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However I'm concerned that for this OP, adding details about CMOS which don't apply to his question (and having to differentiate between things like HC and HCT, which are both CMOS but have different thresholds, of course) could add more *confusion*, than they add *value* in this specific case, unless I write a *much* longer answer which can't be done in the available time today. I've also been criticised in the past for writing answers that are too long, so I won't do that this time. Anyway, again, nice answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Let's do this in three stages:

- Your schematic shows that the LED requires a low voltage at its cathode, in order to light, since its anode is connected to +5V via a resistor.
- Your schematic also shows an inverter (NOT) gate, meaning that a logic 1 on its input will cause a logic 0 on its output and vice-versa.

  A logic 0 on the output of the inverter will be a (relatively) low voltage, and that is when the LED will illuminate. As explained above, a logic 0 on the output of the inverter will result from a logic 1 being detected on its input.

  Therefore: Logic 1 on the input = LED lit.
- So what is the voltage for a logic 1 on the inverter gate's input? That depends on the logic family of that gate, and for some logic families, also depends on the power supply voltage used for that gate (which, although not shown on your schematic, we can probably assume to also be +5V).

  You can find the answer in the datasheet for whatever logic family is used for that.

  - An input voltage above **V<sub>IH</sub>** will definitely be considered as a logic 1 and will cause the LED to be lit (on).
  - An input voltage below **V<sub>IL</sub>** will definitely be considered as a logic 0 and will cause the LED to be unlit (off).
  - An input voltage between **V<sub>IL</sub>** and **V<sub>IH</sub>** could result in the LED being on or off, you can't be sure of either result.

---

While I've been typing, you've added that the chip is a 74LS00 powered from +5V, and so actually the inverter gate in the schematic will be one NAND gate from the LS00, with its two inputs connected together.

You can find the input voltage levels that I mentioned above, in the LS00 datasheet, and they are the standard input thresholds for all LS TTL family devices (for compatibility reasons):

- **V<sub>IL</sub>** = 0.8V
- **V<sub>IH</sub>** = 2.0V

Comment: Although *Transistor* has written an excellent answer at the same time as I've been typing mine, I'll leave mine here in case it says things differently, in a way that helps.